# Openlayers with Cached Bing Maps?

Tags: openlayers, bing-maps

I want to use a folder with cached bing map tiles for using it with openlayers 2.
After a google search, i haven't find any example on how to use the tiles locally. The tiles are saved as ".png" in my folder. For example the following image is saved as 1221002.png

---

[image]

---

The only example that i have found is this link from openlayers site
https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLayers_Local_Tiles_Example

with the following piece of code

`// This is the layer that uses the locally stored tiles 
 var newLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM(
             "Local Tiles", 
             "tiles/${z}/${x}/${y}.png", 
             {numZoomLevels: 19, 
              alpha: true, 
              isBaseLayer: false}
         );`

What i have tried so far is to set my code as follows

```
var newLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM(
         "Local Tiles", 
         "tiles/${z}${x}${y}.png",           <--- Slashes removed
         {numZoomLevels: 19, 
          alpha: true, 
          isBaseLayer: false}
     );
```

but with no luck.
Is this the correct approach?

Comment: don't remove the slashes and your path should be something like ('FolderPath/FolderName/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').

Comment: The Bing Maps terms of use do not allow storing the map tiles offline (Ie caching).